# Does using a display template with IEnumerable cause slowness?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, templates

So I decided to have some fun with the numerous posts I saw on here about the "correct" way to use a display template when working with `IEnumerable<T>`.

I have a table that is getting created and for the rows I made a separate display template.  The model in this case is an `IEnumerable<PartTest>`:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Job Number</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Tester</th>
            <th>Pass / Fail</th>
            <th>Test Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Any())
        {
            using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Render Table"))
            {
                Html.DisplayFor(model => model);
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">No results - update search fields</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Template:

```
@model PartTest

<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.JobNumber)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PartNumber)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Tester)</td>
    <td>
        @if (Model.IsPassing)
        {
            <div class="label label-success label-small">Passed</div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="label label-danger label-small">Failed</div>
        }
    </td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TestDate)</td>
</tr>
```

I am using Areas so the path is `~/Areas/PartsTesting/Views/Shared/PartTest.cshtml`.
When I run this it runs horribly slow.  I mean sometimes 10-15 seconds.  The data set is not outrageous, but sometimes it can be upwards of 100+ items in which case I provide a scrollbar, but I didn't think rendering 100 rows would cause this kind of slowness.

When I switched to just manually iterating over the items in a for loop and skipping the display template all together, it ran with 200+ items in ~40ms.  What is going on here?  Why is it so slow when I use display templates (which from what I've read is a "better" way to write for MVC)?

Comment: I think it looks for the file each iteration of the loop. set debug to false

Comment: This is interesting.  The speeds are comparable when I turn off debugging.  I'm not sure the difference in time is tolerable though to warrant using the display templates.  Waiting for potentially more than 20 seconds per run is not an acceptable use of my time when testing.  I like the concept of using display templates, but not at the cost of losing time.

Comment: Personally I don't like templates either. I suggest you try Partial views instead

Comment: @Ewan if you want to write that up as the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Ewan: Display/editor templates *are* partial views. There's absolutely no difference performance wise between using something like `Html.DisplayFor` versus `Html.Partial`, because they essentially do the same thing: render a partial view.

Comment: perhaps its just that im on a later version of MVC or something then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in http://forums.asp.net/t/1614418.aspx?+Html+DisplayFor+item+item+Property+extremely+slow

"When debugging is on, we don't cache the mapping from view name to view file"

"Setting debug=true disables optimized code paths to assist in debugging.  In your particular case, it's disabling view location caching."

It seems that each call to Html.DisplayFor will search for a matching template. Obviously this file operation, with all the attendant checks for whether the file exists etc is pretty slow.

Setting debug to false will optimize away this problem.

Personally though....
I would suggest you try using Html.RenderPartial instead of Html.DisplayFor.

Although, expert opinion is that this will suffer from the same problem. I have always hated templates and think they are 'old skool'

Comment: It's important to mention that `Html.RenderPartial` would only be more efficient if the partial actually dealt with the entire enumerable at once. It's true that the nature of display templates is that they deal with only single items, so the template must be rendered for each item in the enumerable. Calling `Html.RenderPartial` for each item within a for loop would be the exact same scenario.

Comment: I'll take your word for it, although it is obviously slightly different in that you specify the view name and it looks for views rather than templates etc. perhaps the OP could run a quick test?

Comment: That was the point of my other comment. They're both views. A display template is just a partial view. It's just one that follows certain conventions on naming and location to make it work with `DisplayFor`.

Comment: OK I tested it. both are equally fast for me debug=true mvc 5

Comment: I switched to using a for loop and simply just moved the display template into the parent view.  I originally tried it per a suggestion by other SO users and have found it to be a complete waste of time in this instance.  It's useful for other things but this is not one of them.